# Kubernetes Job should use all available resources

Tags: kubernetes

I run a Kubernetes job with thousands of workers following the pattern described in [Coarse Parallel Processing Using a Work Queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/). I use the Python client for the Kubernetes API to define the job programmatically. The cluster does not scale automatically. The available resources are unknown at the time of programming.

The goal is to use all available resources of the cluster for my job. I have tried to optimise the `.spec.parallelism` setting. If I set `.spec.parallelism` and `.spec.completions` to the same value, all pods for the job are started at the beginning, but most of them could not be scheduled due to resource requirements (e.g. insufficient CPU). When the first pods are finished, the resources are free and more pods are scheduled. But after some time (2.4 hours on my cluster) Kubernetes gives up scheduling the remaining pods and marks them as failed, which eventually causes the whole job to fail.

Is there a pattern for a job on a Kubernetes cluster to use all available resources?

Comment: "The available resources are unknown at the time of programming." But are they known at the time of deployment? Could you provide your Python tooling with an environment variable to tune `.spec.parallelism` and `.spec.completions`? Is this a multi-tenant cluster?

Comment: Instead of launching a separate Job per task, could you launch a Deployment with long-running workers that read jobs off the queue and don't exit?  That would be easier to develop and manage in a couple of ways; if you wanted a manual and cluster-specific setup, you could set a single worker's resource requests to a complete node's capacity, and the Deployment `replicas:` to the number of nodes.

Comment: Another approach could be to have your coordinator process be a long-running process that incrementally creates Jobs as other Jobs finish.  That would avoid the problem where Jobs are waiting for hours and never complete, and also decrease the load on the Kubernetes scheduler somewhat.